# How to provide equal spacing between CardViews of uneven height?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

I've a screen with 3 card views arranged vertically. The number of cards is fixed at 3. The cards have different heights because their contents are different. I would like to divide the spacing between the cards equally so that the three cards takes up the whole screen space equally instead of a large empty space between third card and bottom of the screen as shown in the image below (which is my screen right now).

I tried providing Space element between Card Views as follows but it isn't doing anything:

```
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Space>
```

I also tried adding **weightSum** to the parent Linear Layout to no avail. Is there a way to do this?

[image: my screen].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are there already, but instead of Space, just use an empty View to create the spacing.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

<View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" /> 

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

<View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" /> 

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

<View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Could you please tell why <Space> didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to split the spaces between the cards, you can try using constraintLayout with a spread chain or spread inside chain. https://medium.com/@loutry/guide-to-constraintlayout-407cd87bc013

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, I use `ConstraintLayout`:

Import the lib:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/card2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/card3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card1">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card2">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So you have fixed 3 `CardView`:

- Its height is `wrap_content`
- Each card has both constraint to the top and bottom (the first card stick to parent top and the last card stick to parent bottom)

`ConstraintLayout` is in charge of pull the spacing out equally to match all the constraint we set up. But be sure that your content is not too long, the top and bottom will be clipped out.

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Angel Koh's answer worked. So I'm accepting it as answer since it required very little modifications. I haven't tried your answer yet. Is there any advantage (like performance) to your answer compared to his?

Comment: `ConstraintLayout` is efficient for complex layout and can help you avoid many nested `ViewGroup`. In this situation, you only have 1 direction constraint, which is vertical, using @Angel Koh 's answer will be better in performance. TIL :D